# how to update user details after creating users using accounts-unstyled,accounts-password

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I am creating a meteor app where the admin should have the ability to edit user details.I have used **accounts-unstyled**,**accounts-password** packages to create the user registrations.I used {{atForm}} to create user registration form. Now I want to create a separate page for admins where they can edit user details.What is the easiest way for me to implement the functionality to edit user details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastest way would be to use one of the existing packages like this one https://atmospherejs.com/apinf/accounts-admin-ui

Alternative is to make custom solution - docs: https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html

Comment: please look into this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563507/load-collections-to-a-quickform-in-meteor)