# load collections to a quickform in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

I created two seperate schemas for `payments` collection and `memberProfile`. Now I need to create a **quickform** so I could load all the payments relevant to a unique memberProfile.

```
     //The code for memberPayment collection

MemberProfiles = new Mongo.Collection('memberProfiles');


RecipeSchema = new SimpleSchema({
name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Name"
},
desc: {
    type: String,
    label: "Description"
},
payments:{
    type: [PaymentSchema],
    autoValue: function () {
        return Payments.find({ memberId="uniqueId"});
    },

     defaultValue: function () {
         return Payments.find({memberId="uniqueId"});
    },

},

// The code for payments collection

 PaymentSchema = new SimpleSchema({
name:{
    type: String

},
amount:{
    type: String
},
memberId:{
    type: String
},


});
```

This code doesn't work.

Comment: And what's your autoform like?

Comment: my code to create the quickform is,   {{> quickForm collection="MemberProfiles" id="insertMemberProfileForm" type="insert" }}

Comment: Looks like you're missing the ```schema``` attribute? Any autoform needs to take in a ```schema``` attribute that explicitly tells autoform to use that schema to generate the necessary form. Check [this](http://autoform.meteorapp.com/quickform) page out for  demos using autoform.

Comment: thanks .....................

Comment: Not sure if that helped you resolve your problem, I shall publish my comment as the answer. You may accept it if it helped.

Comment: thanks it surely helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the schema attribute. Any autoform needs to take in a schema attribute that explicitly tells autoform to use that schema to generate the necessary form. Check [this](http://autoform.meteorapp.com/quickform) page out for demos using autoform.

```
{{> quickForm collection="theMongoCollection" id="theFormID" schema="theSchemaName" type="typeOfForm" }}
```